# Alternative of using list of ids in url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, url, routes

Currently i have a MVC 3 project and i am using {controller}/{action}/{id} as routing and manage to use the {id} as a list of ids in one string comma separated {"id1,id2,id3"} it works perfect but passing the ids in the URL do not sound good for me as it could be a list of 100 or more ids (in the URL that's not good or even functional).
so please is there a better approach to do this?

Comment: for certain cases i want to filter a database result,

Comment: if you want this url to be shareable, you can store the group of ids in a database and expose it through a single id pointing to that group.

Answer (score 0):

Check your database, is there a parent / child relationship you can leverage? For example:

```
parent> id: 1

child> id: 1, parent_id: 1
child> id: 2, parent_id: 1
child> id: 3, parent_id: 1
```

If not, I think you are stuck with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options available.

One would be to create a Model with a list of the Ids you are wanting to keep stored away.  You could store those Ids in your View in a Hidden Field, and then when calling your Action you just pass the Model back.

Another would be to use a Session variable to keep the list of Ids.  Of course, this is time sensitive (default time for Session is 5 minutes I believe).  If it needs to remain longer, you would need to look into other ideas.

Those are the first few that came to mind.  There are many other creative solutions but might not be feasible or of use.